# Save /etc/X11/xorg.conf on reboot

Tags: xorg, nvidia, lubuntu

with my `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-xconfig` i can create the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file

```
>>> sudo nvidia-xconfig
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
WARNING: Unable to find CorePointer in X configuration; attempting to add new CorePointer section.
WARNING: The CorePointer device was not specified explicitly in the layout; using the first mouse device.
WARNING: Unable to find CoreKeyboard in X configuration; attempting to add new CoreKeyboard section.
WARNING: The CoreKeyboard device was not specified explicitly in the layout; using the first keyboard device.
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

i will set the `cool-bits` option with

```
>>> sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=12
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

But every time I reboot my options are gone..

The problem is that the `cool-bits` option allows me to overclock. But i need to reboot after to apply the effect but if I reboot the file disappears

I use lubuntu 17.10

EDIT:

Ah, I think a package is missing but I don't know which one

```
Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing xorg-server.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found`
```

Comment: seems the files are written, did you do a diff to see if any actual change was made?

Comment: Ah, I think a package is missing but I don't know which one

`Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found`

Comment: The only change on file comes with the command `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=12`.
After i reboot to apply but disappears on startup

Comment: Can you explain what the "cool-bits" actually do? Does it add some text to `xorg.conf`? `xorg.conf`should not be touched on reboot. Unless something it writing to it on reboot. But I can't think why.

Comment: According to the [readme nvidia 387.12](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/387.12/README/xconfigoptions.html) --cool-bits=12 add text like `Option "Coolbits" "integer"` on devices section in `xorg.conf`

Comment: So... after you reboot your PC, what does this show: `grep Option /etc/X11/xorg.conf`